# Cant' make nodejs webapp compile on azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying out azure devops for developing projects. The main focus I'm looking for is the security, from what I have seen, your code gets scanned and recommendations about what you should change pop up to you.

For testing how this worked, I'm trying to upload the code of a vulnerable webapp so I can see what azure actually tells me about it.

For that I'm using the well known WebGoat-Legacy, which is used by pentesters to practice at the start.

I downloaded the repository and uploaded it to azure, when I go to the build part, Apache Maven is recommended so I use that.

App is built correctly and no errors pop up on the build part. I go on release part then.

For release I chose "Azure app service deployment". I set up the stage and enter

`'Run on agent'.'Deploy Azure App Service'` on `AppService Name`. I save and create the release.

When that part comes, I get the following error

`No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip`

From what I have searched, thats a pretty common error so I tried the following

- Setting "Package or Folder to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test-CI\drop\s\build`"

got error `No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\test\drop\s\build`

- Adding `- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1` to pipelines

On build i get `##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.`
Get Error `No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip`

Any idea on what can I do? I just want to see what results azure returns regarding vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'
```

Based on this error message, we can know that the release did not find the generated .zip file because the build artifacts are empty.

The reason caused this issue could be you did't copy anything to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) in your definition.To solve this issue,you need to add a '**Copy Files**'-Task before the 'PublishBuildArtifacts' task.

[image]

If you do not add a copy file task, you will receive a warning as shown below.

[image]

For the similar thread,please refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7247) on github.